# Does python support multiple inheritance?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

1. Does Python Support Multiple Inheritance? if not then any other alternatives for multiple inheritance?
2. Can we do method overloading in python?

Comment: Just one thing. Do you really understand what multiple inheritance is? Did you use in, say, C++ or is Python your first try on OOP? If so, consider that languages like Java and C# did intentionally do without multiple inheritance because it has a conceptual complexity that is easily underestimated. Before diving into this I'd recommend to read more about why it is so difficult to *really* understand and use and how to avoid it... just my two cents :) Good study and coding to you!

Comment: At least study and understand the "Diamond problem"!

Comment: @pid yes i know what the multiple inheritance is. I was learnt oop concepts in java and handle multiple inheritance using interface but in python there is a lot of oop concepts which are not directly availabe for example __ for declaring the method as abstract.'abc' module for abstraction and so on but what i want to know here is python support multiple inheritance directly or not? because python does not support interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes python supports multiple inheritance.

> Here is a example:

```
class Base1:
    pass
class Base2:
    pass
class MultiDerived(Base1, Base2):
    pass
```

[image: pic1]

> And another example:

```
class Base:
    pass
class Derived1(Base):
    pass
class Derived2(Derived1):
    pass
```

[image: pic2]

Yes, python does support function overloading.

Comment: For first exmple:
Does this approach works when both base1 and base2 have concrete methods?

Comment: thanks for your response. yes i try and implement your first example and it works fine.now i totally understand how to handle multiple inheritance in python.

Comment: Yes, Sheri i think so, if there are concrete methods then the function in that object gets called. If there are abstract methods than the child overrides the method of parent class.